# Запрос к бд на вывод записей за указанную дату

Tags: php, mysql

Есть у меня форма с выбором даты:

```
<form method="post" name="date" action="date.php" >
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="delivery_date" value="<?=htmlspecialchars(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($users['delivery_date'])), ENT_QUOTES)?>" id="example-date-input"> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mb-3">Найти</button>
 </form>
```

Мне нужно вывести из бд все записи за указанную дату, пытаюсь сделать так:

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['date']))
{
$date = ($_POST['date']);

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE delivery_date='$date' AND delivery='1' ORDER BY id DESC";
print_r ($_POST);
$result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);

if ($result) {
  header('Location:print.php');
}
else {
    printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
}
?>
```

Правильно ли составлен скриgт с запросом?
И как корректно вывести данные? Пытаюсь вывести все записи по указанной дате.

Comment: совсем неправильно. Огромная куча ошибок

Comment: @Ипатьев может тогда хотя бы объясните? :(

Comment: невозможно научить программированию в комментарии длиной в 20 слов. Вы же не пишете осмысленный код, вы собираете его из кубиков, просто нагромождая их друг на друга, выдергивая из какого-то другого места. Чтобы я мог объяснить, вы должны сами понимать, что такое $dbtable и откуда оно здесь вообще могло взяться. Зачем здесь функция. откуда в ней должна взяться $date. Я предлагаю начать с основ. Сначала освоить SQL. потом научиться работать с БД через PDO и подготовленные выражения. потом научиться работать с данными из форм. И только потом пытаться завернуть все это в функцию

Comment: @Ипатьев я код прикрепил не целиком, поправил.$dbtable - это название таблицы, берётся из другого файла.

Comment: надо убрать функцию и поменять код так чтобы он выполнял запрос через подготовленные выражения ,а не вставлял переменные напрямую в запрос

Comment: кстати, код $date = `date('Y-m-d', ['delivery_date'];` является полнейшей, абсолютной бессмыслицей

Comment: @Ипатьев я поменял код в php, проверил, оправляет дату в нужном формате. 
Мне нужно объяснить на примере, как мне теперь вывести данные из таблицы за эту дату :( Простите, я тупой

Answer (score 0):

Название таблицы следует не брать из файла, а писать прямо в запросе.
Вместо mysqli следует использовать PDO. Код для db.php брать [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)
Функцию убрать из кода, она тут не имеет смысла.

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['date']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE delivery_date=? ORDER BY id DESC";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['date']]);
    $del_date = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Если в $_POST['date'] содержится дата в формате 2019-03-29 то gосле выполнения этого кода в переменной $del_date будет массив со всеми записями на нужную дату

Comment: Вместо mysqli следует использовать PDO
Это навязывание своего мнения, или рекомендация?)

Comment: @Dizzy221 перепиши этот код на mysqli, сравни что получилось

Comment: Самое главное - как мне корректно это вывести на странице?

Comment: @web2k17 в цикле. любые операции с массивами производятся с помощью циклов